# Difference between 'is <constantpattern>' and '== constant'

Tags: pattern-matching, c#-7.0

C# 7.0 introduced pattern matching, and one of patterns is **constant pattern**.

So one can now write:

```
int? i = 0
if (i is null) {..}
```

or even

```
if (i is 0) {..}
```

How this compares with `==` equality?

Which operator is used to compare values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int? i = 0;
if (i is null) {}
if (i is 0) {}
```

is translated into:

```
int? num = 0;
if (!num.HasValue) {}
if (object.Equals(0, num)) {}
```

[sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANAJiA1AHwAIAYAEqCMBuAWAChUBmbAJkwGFiBvYzJ7c1KTAWQAoBKR5hkWbDMASwB2AFwD8YzAF5M6QkQCQq0QDNMXUWIDOmcQFcANqZ6Y6AX34ix23QaWWbdzLaLWgA==)

Comment: What is that site? And Why *i is 0* is translated to *i not equals 0*?

Comment: That site is a C# compiler play field. Probably a bug on the site.

Comment: Yeah, I understood it is a playground. But I don't understand what it does, what is that output? It's not IL, so which transformations are applied?

Comment: It's the lowering of the code to more basic C# constructs.

Comment: Interesting thing!

Comment: About the "bug", I verified that if you put nothing between the last `if` braces, it reverses the condition. If you put something, the condition is written correctly.

Comment: I think the site uses ILSpy to decompile. The compiler must be generating that code as an optimization of some sort.